# Itemize with only nested items

Tags: itemize

I want to make a list like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Day 7.
        \item Day 28.
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

But I get an error when compiling:

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{itemize}

The reason I want to do this, is that i have part of a list earlier, and I want to continue it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Each `itemize` will need an item. Just type `\item` as second line of code! For future question: Please always post compilable code. We have no chance to see if your problem appears due to other packages or alike. In this very case, it was easy to spot, but it is not best practise here. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks you. Adding \item[] (to avoid the bullet) fixed it. Can you make your comment an answer, so i can close the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each itemize will need an item. Just type \item as second line of code!

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item%
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Day 7.
        \item Day 28.
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

If you need to omit the bullet, just use `\item[]`.

Comment: thank you for sharing. It worked for me!!